American politicians with Indian vs. Chinese roots
As of 2019, there were 5,400,000 Chinese-Americans living in the USA. On the other hand, as of 2020, there were 4,397,737 Indian-American living in the USA.
In the case of myself, I can name a few Indian-American politicians off the top of my head.

Kamala Harris
Tulsi Gabbard
Vivek Ramaswamy
Pramila Jayapal
Nikki Haley

However, I cannot say I can do the same for Chinese Americans.
Why are there so many prominent (either vocal or influential or visible) American politicians with visible Indian roots; however, there are no prominent politicians with visible Chinese roots?

In spite of her first name and her and her mother's spirituality, it seems Tulsi Gabbard does not have any direct Indian roots.

@Relaxed - Yes, mentioned in my answer.

There has been another question here that I vaguely recall but can't find, about the relative underrepresentation of people with Hong Kong Chinese ancestry/ethnicity in the UK Parliament (in comparison to other non-white ethnicities)

Andrew Yang ? See also: Category:American politicians of Chinese descent

If the premise is true, one could certainly make a lot of hypotheses about relative democratic political participation in people's ancestors' countries of origin, acceptance within major parties, the historical context of the Chinese Exclusion Act, and so forth.
But I am not sure the premise of the question is correct. We simply do not have enough data to say for sure. Major Chinese-American politicians, whether as presidential candidates, cabinet members, or congresspeople, have included Andrew Yang, Tammy Duckworth, TJ Cox, Elaine Chao and so forth. I'd put Yang on the same level as Ramaswamy or Haley in terms of how well they're known, and Jayapal and Duckworth are similar, for instance.
Obviously, none of them have it to the presidential nomination of a major party, yet, but that's a sample size of one for Indian Americans that was zero as of six months ago, so there's not much difference there.
If we look at the past and current members of the US congress, there have been seven Chinese-American US representatives (counting Taiwan, which both the PRC and ROC officially classify as part of China), and nine Indian-American representatives, including one who was just elected. There have been three Chinese-American senators and one Indian-American senator (Harris herself). There have been 8 Chinese-American congresspeople overall—Duckworth and Akaka have to be excluded once each, since they served in both chambers—and 10 Indian-American congresspeople.
Statistically, these numbers are indistinguishable, which is what we might expect given the similar population sizes (see appendix).
As of the next congress, there will be six Indian American politicians in Congress, and only three Chinese-American politicians, but it's hard to tell whether this represents an actual trend or more of a historical accident (four of the first group were elected in the same year, so if you had asked this question 15 years ago, the answer might have been pretty different).
Note that Tulsi Gabbard is not Indian American, but rather a European-American and Samoan-American Hindu. Her mother was born in Indiana, though, which might easily be mistaken for India on a cursory glance at her biography.

Appendix:
As of 2020, the Chinese-American and Indian-American populations of the USA estimated by the US census were a little different from the question, but not much: 5,205,461 and 4,768,846 (note also that the counts are probably slightly off in the ones or tens digit because of intentional random inaccuracies added to prevent people from being able to identify specific individuals).
As mentioned previously, 8 Chinese Americans and 10 Indian Americans have served in the Congress; the total number of people to ever serve in Congress is around 12,691. With these numbers, we can calculate proportions (e.g. the number of Chinese Americans as a proportion of Chinese Americans plus Indian Americans for the nation as a whole and for the Congress). The actual frequencies are [10, 8], and the expected frequencies are [8.6, 9.4]. Note that we restrict our set and calculate proportions based only on Indian-American and Chinese-American members of Congress and of the general population, excluding other groups; otherwise, we would be considering the overall historical underrepresentation of Indian-American and Chinese-American politicians relative to other groups in Congress.
We can perform an exact binomial test on these frequencies (since "Chinese American" is the complement of "Indian American" in the restricted set under consideration), obtaining a p-value of 0.63. This suggests a 63% probability of obtaining results at least as extreme via a binomial process under the null hypothesis that the probability of a Chinese American being elected relative to an Indian American or vice versa reflects the population proportion. We could also do a one-sided test to look at the probability of a result this extreme assuming that Indian Americans were not overrepresented, with a p-value of 0.34. Neither of these would be considered significant results in most contexts.
We might also want to be a little more careful and ask the following question: if each election is a random selection from a multinomial distribution (i.e. including the group "neither Chinese American nor Indian American"), the underrepresentation of Indian + Chinese American groups in the Congress is known (given by 18/12691), and the null hypothesis is that given this representation, Indian American and Chinese American congresspeople historically have been equally underrepresented (in proportion to their population percentages), what is the probability or p-value of obtaining a result at least as extreme (i.e. at least 25% more Indian-American congresspeople than Chinese-American congresspeople) under the null hypothesis? In this case, the answer is about 27%, which again would not be considered significant in most cases.
Note that a χ-squared test on the relative frequencies gives a similar result, but an exact test is necessary to be certain because of the low frequencies.
However, approximations aside, a binomial, multinomial or χ-square test is not precisely the correct test for this, because the proportions of Chinese and Asian Americans change over time and the current Congress is the product of multiple discrete election cycles at set time intervals; furthermore, with Asian-American senators and representatives disproportionately concentrated in specific states, and the unlikelihood of uncorrelated trials (i.e. elections of one person from a given nationally underrepresented group very likely can produce a higher likelihood of further election), there is much more complexity. A proper analysis of the null hypothesis would require a bootstrap estimate of the significance from an appropriate simulation.

Very informative answer. What about the overall representation of Indian and Chinese Americans? Are the combined numbers of elected persons roughly equal to the share of population?

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - I added an appendix addressing that. Basically, we don't want to know whether Chinese-Americans and Indian-Americans, combined, are underrepresented in the US Congress (I am pretty sure they are), but rather whether Indian Americans are overrepresented relative to Chinese Americans in the set of both groups in the Congress. In essence, we have a set of 18 people, and we can code a success any way we like (it makes no difference to the calculation), say, 10 successes. Then we can do an exact binomial test to estimate the probability of generating a result...

...that extreme if the actual probability of the event is equal to the population percentage (0.48, with the given numbers of Indian and Chinese Americans). Depending on the precise nuance of the null hypothesis, the p-value is 0.63 or 0.34. Most people set their significance level for these kinds of tests at 5% or lower, so they would not reject the null hypothesis. A full analysis would need to take into account substantial temporal and geographical variation, though, so this should only be seen as quantifying our uncertainty.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - Also, it is important to know what we are testing here. Each election is "actually" a sample from a multinomial distribution with three outcomes: (X) Chinese American, (Y) Indian American, (Z) neither Chinese American nor Indian American. We can prove that if the number of people in that third group is given (whatever it might be, as long as we know it), then the conditional probability of being in group X or group Y follows a binomial distribution.

@NoDataDumpNoContribution - But for a somewhat more careful formulation of the question, see the paragraph that I just added.
